# Duplicate Values with Foreign Key in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a few models in my django app that look like this:

```
class WHID(models.Model):
    whid = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    whid = models.ForeignKey(WHID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to have it so that I can't create a duplicate Department name for each WHID.

So if I have two entries in the WHID table:

```
 id  whid 
  1  whid1
  2  whid2
```

Then in the Department table:

```
  name         whid
  Department1    1
  Department1    2
  Department2    1
  Department2    2
  Department1    1 <----How do I stop this record from being created
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [`UniqueContraint(fields=['name', 'whid'])`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) in the model Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `unique=True` in the `ForeignKey`, but this is basically a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) then, so you can rewrite your model to:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    whid = models.OneToOneField(WHID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you however want to allow *multiple* `Department`s for a given `WHID`, but with *unique* `name`s for the same `WHID`, you can make use since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2) of a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint):

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    whid = models.ForeignKey(WHID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint('name', 'whid', name='whid_name')
        ]
```

or prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can make use of [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    whid = models.ForeignKey(WHID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            ['name', 'whid']
        ]
```

Comment: Added more data to the Department records for clarification. I don't think the OneToOne is what I need here, since I can have multiple Departments to the same WHID